# Sharepoint Client model - request timeout

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am receiving a timeout from the Sharepoint Client Managed Object model.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The operation has timed out.
```

Basically, I am batching 100 updates and sending them at one go. It is no problem for me if takes time but I really want to avoid timeout exception.

I have tried in a million of ways to increase the timeout in the client context but they were all without success. I have used reflection to try to identity what the sharepoint is doing when calling the executequery method of the client context. sharepoint is basically creating an HttpWebRequest and sending it.

I have ended with the below code, but still without success:

```
 public static void SetInfinteTimeout(this ClientContext ctx)
{
    int timeout = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    ctx.RequestTimeout = timeout;
    ctx.PendingRequest.RequestExecutor.RequestKeepAlive = false;            
    ctx.PendingRequest.RequestExecutor.WebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    ctx.PendingRequest.RequestExecutor.WebRequest.Timeout = timeout;
    ctx.PendingRequest.RequestExecutor.WebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = timeout;            
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 2000;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 1000;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(false, 0, 0); 
    ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = timeout; // 10 minutes       

}
```

But I am still receiving a timeout error! 

Is there anything else that I am missing please?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use clientcallablesettings (SPWebApplication.ClientCallableSettings):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.clientcallablesettings.aspx

This has an execution timeout property and other related settings.

In my case, I needed to add this in the Upgrade Actions as per the below code

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
      site.WebApplication.ClientCallableSettings.ExecutionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
      site.WebApplication.ClientCallableSettings.MaxObjectPaths = 1000;
      site.WebApplication.ClientCallableSettings.MaxResourcesPerRequest = 1000;
      site.WebApplication.ClientCallableSettings.EnableStackTrace = true;
      site.WebApplication.Update();
}
```

Comment: OK, but how do you get the SPWebApplication ?

Comment: The best solution is to use Server Object Modeal instead of Client Object Model .With Server Object Model you won't face these problems and won't need to tweak/change SP settings and you'll avoid a lot of headache.

Comment: @JosephCaruana Can you post your solution, what exactly did you do with ClientCallable settings? The link that you have in the answer just has the declaration of the property

Comment: @JosephCaruana could you give a snippet for how you used clientcallablesettings ExecutionTimeout ?

Comment: @AhmedHussein, I have updated my answer to include a code sample - hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

- keeping default KeepAlive (true),
- disabling Timeout and
- keeping default MaxServicePointIdleTime value (which is 100 seconds by
  default but you set to 2).

Just as:

```
public static void SetInfiniteTimeout(this ClientContext ctx)
{
    ctx.RequestTimeout = -1;  //ctx.RequestTimeout or System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;
}
```

Also, how many seconds it takes for you to get timeout error, in your current configuration?

Comment: Hi - thank you for your kind reply. Yes, I had tried all the timeout settings. It was timing out after 1.5 mins. In the end, the problem was solved by using client callable settings. Thanks again. +1 for the input.